# Get dropdown value on mouse up with jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get the value of a dropdown when the user selects that option, and the way I am doing it is a bit buggy, it tends to only work sometimes. I was wondering if there is a better way. Here is how I am doing it now:

```
$("#Legal_Status").mouseup(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Married") {
        alert("married")
    }
}); 

<select name="Legal_Status" id="Legal_Status">
                        <option value="none selected">--select one--</option>
                        <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
                        <option value="Single">Single</option>
                        <option value="Married">Married</option>
                        <option value="Divorced">Divorced</option>
                        <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aguM2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `change` event instead:

```
$("#Legal_Status").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Married") {
        alert("married")
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gb8y5/